# Can't find httpd.conf

Tags: 14.04, apache2, php, webserver

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a laptop and installed apache 2 (version  2.4.7) and PHP 5.

I cannot find `httpd.conf`. I need to change it because when I try to open a .php page I see a download box.

How should I proceed?

Comment: I believe you are asking the wrong question. The question you should ask is "how do I prevent this download box from showing" + "see the image I added". If that would have "edit httpd.conf with..."  as an answer ou'd have a good q and good a. Now you will get negative answers about httpd.conf where you have no interest in since you still have a download box ;)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Ubuntu doesn't use `httpd.conf` as standard, instead global configuration stuff for apache is found in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. You can create a `httpd.conf` in the apache2 directory, and load any further configuration from it by including the following line in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf.`

```
Include /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

You don't need that file to configure apache, but you can create it if other software relies on it being there.

Comment: Arronical where will put configuration which needs to go into the `httpd.conf` file? I am following this tutorial to setup glassfish behind apache https://www.e2enetworks.com/help/knowledge-base/setting-up-glassfish-behind-apache/

Comment: Any chance this include may get overwritten if I upgrade Apache?

Comment: finally a clear answer...

Answer (score 19):

`httpd.conf` will be in `/etc/apache2/`.

```
/etc/apache2$ ls
apache2.conf  envvars     mods-available  ports.conf       sites-enabled
conf.d        httpd.conf  mods-enabled    sites-available
:/etc/apache2$ more httpd.conf
:/etc/apache2$
```

> I need to change it

No, you do not. [The documentation states](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html):

> httpd.conf: historically the main Apache2 configuration file, named after the httpd daemon. Now the file does not exist. In older versions of Ubuntu the file might be present, but empty, as all configuration options have been moved to the below referenced directories.
>
> because when I try to open a .php page I see a download box

How would changing `httpd.conf` fix that?
If you need config settings changed I would assume you need to alter `apache2.conf` or  the virtual host in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`.

Comment: actually what I see is the apache2.conf