# Edit httpd.conf for restricting the user to access it from specific IP address

Tags: permissions, apache2, 14.10, configuration

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS server.

I want to restrict user from accessing a sub-domain. So I searched across web, so [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-restrict-access-based-on-ip-address-to-selected-directories/) link I found helpful but I can not access `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file as it not exist.

So I searched for the better answer. I got [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/652100/117066), But then I thought that I should make change in that domain conf file instead of following [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/652100/117066) link.

But Now I am thinking to make changes in `conf` file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` folder for that domain.

Here is that file looks like

```
ServerAdmin info@domain.com
ServerName asd.domain.com
ServerAlias asd.domain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html/asd.domain.com
```

And now I added one line as follows

```
Allow from <my.ip.address.000>
```

But now I am not able to restart the because `Allow` is not allowed.
Can anybody help on this?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Answer (score 0):

It's more versatile to do this via .htaccess.

This will prevent the files to be read, even if you have a configuration problem allowing the folder to be accessed another way, like if it's a subdirectory of your root (e.g. /var/www/mysubdomain).

```
# ALLOW USER BY IP
<Limit GET POST>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from 1.2.3.4
</Limit>
```

Just change the IP 1.2.3.4 to your allowed address range.

Comment: what are the advantages and disadvantages if we get this done by `.htaccess`?

How we can accomplish using `.conf` file?

Comment: I don't know any disadvantage at the moment, but the advantage is in my answer. Additionally, no need to restart apache on changes.