# Can I add my .htaccess config to my sites-enabled virtual host .conf file?

Tags: server, apache2, virtualhost, .htaccess

I understand that httpd.conf is no longer available in Apache at /etc/apache2. A fix is that I could create a httpd.conf file as detailed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652095/cant-find-httpd-conf) and point my apache2.conf to it.

But browsing through the apache2.conf, I noticed this:

```
# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

Does this mean that I can safely add my .htaccess configs to my .conf file at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.com.conf ?

Adding server configs to .htaccess can slow things down, especially when you add a bunch of them as shown [here](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-apache/blob/master/dist/.htaccess), and I want to make sure I'm adding them in the most prudent location.

Comment: If Apache 2 is setup to use VirtualHosting then you put the `.htacess` file in the root directory of each host.  There's no need to add any conf files...

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But I also have read that having a bunch of configure in .htaccess can slow down page delivery time? So, my goal was to move these settings to a location where it would not have this effect - basically closer to the core of Apache.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a .conf file for your site in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/` and put there all your server settings that you don't want in `.htaccess`.
Then enable that config using `a2enconf` (which will create a symlink in  `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

See `/usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz` for more about how the Apache configuration is handled in Debian and its derivatives like Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the directives being used in the `.htaccess` file.

You can't necessarily simply copy (or *include*) the same directives from `.htaccess` and use them unaltered in a *server* or *virtualhost* context, which is suggested here. `.htaccess` files work in a *directory* context, so you can potentially copy them verbatim into a corresponding `<Directory>` container inside the vHost or server config.

The notable directives here are mod_rewrite - which work differently in a *server* (or *virtualhost*) context vs `.htaccess` (or *directory*) context.

For example, if the `.htaccess` file is located at `/var/www/user/public_html/.htaccess` then you could use the following in the vHost container instead:

```
<Directory /var/www/user/public_html>
    # Disable .htaccess overrides
    AllowOverride None

    # .htaccess directives go here...
    # :
</Directory>
```

However, you may not want to do this. It might be preferable to modify the directives so they work in a *virtualhost* context instead. Unless you completely disable `.htaccess` overrides (as mentioned above with `AllowOverride None` and possibly `AllowOverrideList`) then any `.htaccess` file along the filesystem path will *override* the `<Directory>` container in the vHost.

> Adding server configs to `.htaccess` can slow things down

Note that in order to get the (marginal) performance benefit, you need to completely disable `.htaccess` overrides in the server config (as mentioned above). Simply removing the `.htaccess` file(s) is not sufficient since the server will still search for them in every directory along the requested filesystem path.